# Maybe + future tense

Tags: future-tense, informal-language

Should I say (in informal day-to-day speech):

> Maybe **I go** for a walk in hour or so.
>
> Maybe **I go visit James** next week.

or

> Maybe **I will go** for a walk in hour or so.
>
> Maybe **I will go visit James** next week.

*Will* in the later sentences seems superfluous to me, because it's obvious speaker talks of the future events and not of the present ones.

Comment: While you will be understood, this is not proper grammar. "Maybe" doesn't change much here. If you say "I go for a walk in an hour", you will be understood, but the correct usage is "I'll go/ I am going for a walk in an hour".

Comment: @Vilmar Point taken. But I hear much improper grammar in spoken language, which is accepted as long as it is understandable by both parties.

Comment: Yes, you hear a lot of casually improper grammar in spoken language, but this is not one of those cases.  If it's an act in the future, you have to use the future tense.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are wrong.

The second pair is awkward.

The following is largely idiomatic, but it just might point you in the right direction:

> I might go for a walk in hour or so.
>
> Maybe I should visit James next week.
>     I might want to visit James next week.
>
> "Maybe he'll go for a walk in the course of the next hour or so."
>     "Maybe he will. I wouldn't put it past him."
>
> Maybe I should pay James a visit next week.

That said, informal speech relies heavily on contractions.

Comment: I don't understand what's awkward about "Maybe I will go visit James next week" except that we'd usually say "Maybe I'll go..." instead.  They sound normal enough to me as a native speaker.

Comment: That was my impression, but it wasn't clear if that was precisely what you meant.  And if it was not entirely clear to me, it might be even less clear to a non-native speaker.